# The method setAction(String, String) is undefined for the type PlusClient.Builder

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have the code

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setAction("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                    "http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity")
            .setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")        
            .build();
```

How can I get rid of this error? (my sdk is all updated and i have my google-play-services_liv into the project library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
.setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity","http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity") 
.setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")
.build();
```

That's `setActions` with an `s` not `setAction`. I think it was just a typo on your part! :)

Comment: still got this one : "The method setAction(String[]) is undefined for the type PlusClient.Builder"

Comment: I don't see a `setAction` in the docs....Should be `setActions` with an s. Actually that's probably the only problem!

Comment: Dont mind if i ask you, why do i add those two addresses  "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" "http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity"  ?

Comment: I am not familiar with this API but here it says AddActivity is generic and ListenActivity is if your user listens to songs. https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types/